# pm2 'cron_restart' option works wrong

Tags: node.js, cron, pm2

I have a script to run with different cron options configured in `.ts` file.

So, the problem is, when I run this script on different VPSs, the workers are restarting every 15 minutes, when should be restarted every hour.

The last version of this script was exactly with cron option to restart every 15 minutes. But I had already tried deleting and creating daemon of this script again. Maybe someone had the same or similar issue?

```
import * as pm2 from 'pm2';

pm2.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(2)
  }

  pm2.start({
    script: 'npm -- run worker',
    name: 'worker',
    instances: parseInt(process.env.INST_NUM) || 1,
    cron: '0 */1 * * *',
    restart_delay: 60000
  }, (err, apps) => {
    pm2.disconnect()
    if (err) { throw err }
  })
})
```

By the way, one script that I run independently from config manually also restarts every 15 minutes. I run it as `pm2 start npm --name=updater -- run updater`

Also on one server I run two instances of worker as `INST_NUM=2 ts-node --files dir/pm2-worker.ts` AND, the first instance restarts every hour, while the second - every 15 minutes.

What could be a reason of such inconsistent behaviour?